# Mejorar metodo para que regrese un valor de prioriadad dentro de una lista

Tags: c#, poo

Estoy diseñando una vista que muestre la ubicacion de unas cajas en un inventario, lo pondre en una imagen aqui
[image: Como es cuando esta lleno]

En cada cajita el primer dato es el numero de parte, el segundo es la cantidad de cosas que tiene y el tercero es la prioridad en la que tienen que salir y ese metodo es el que quiero arreglar ya que no esta automatico y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo que sea hecho por un metodo, esta es la manera en la que  lo estoy haciendo.

```
 foreach (var p in cajas.OrderBy(c => c.fecha))
            {
                if (p.partNumber == "10-sag")
                {
                    p.fifo = i;
                    i++;
                }

                if (p.partNumber == "10-qt")
                {
                    p.fifo = j;
                    j++;
                }
            }
```

quiero que haga lo mismo lleve un conteo del orden en el que debe ser retirada la caja pero que este conteo sea independiente segun el partNumber, lo que no quiero es que si por ejemplo se ingresa una nueva parte y el partNumber no es ninguno de los dos que estan ahi en el if tener que ir a agregarlo.

Dejo el constructor del objeto tambien

```
  class Caja
    {
        public string partNumber;
        public int fifo;
        public DateTime fecha;
        public int quantity;
        public int position;
        public int orderColumn;
        public int boxnum;

        public Caja(string partNumber, int fifo, int quantity, int position, DateTime fecha, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
        {
            this.partNumber = partNumber;
            this.fifo = fifo;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.position = position;
            this.fecha = fecha;
            this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
            this.boxnum = boxnum;
        }
    }
```

y con este metodo regreso el color de la caja mas vieja sea rojo

```
class CajaCollection : List<Caja>
    {

        public Color ObtenerColorCaja(Caja caja)
        {
            return ObtenerColorCaja(IndexOf(caja));
        }

        public Color ObtenerColorCaja(int index)
        {
            // Localiza la primera caja ordenando por fecha y con el mismo partNumber
            var primeraCaja = this.OrderBy(c => c.fecha)
                .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);

            // Si el índice coincide es la primera a salir (rojo), si no verde
            return index == IndexOf(primeraCaja) ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el mismo criterio para obtener la posición en la cola FIFO que para obtener el color: utilizar un método de la lista:

```
class Caja
{
    public string partNumber;
    public DateTime fecha;
    public int quantity;
    public int position;
    public int orderColumn;
    public int boxnum;

    public Caja(string partNumber, int quantity, int position, DateTime fecha, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
    {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.position = position;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
        this.boxnum = boxnum;
    }
}

class CajaCollection : List<Caja>
{

    public Color ObtenerColorCaja(Caja caja)
    {
        return ObtenerColorCaja(IndexOf(caja));
    }

    public Color ObtenerColorCaja(int index)
    {
        // Si es el primero de la cola rojo, si no verde
        return ObtenerFifo(index) == 1 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }

    public int ObtenerFifo(Caja caja)
    {
        return ObtenerFifo(IndexOf(caja));
    }

    public int ObtenerFifo(int index)
    {
        // Obtiene el orden en la cola filtrado por partNumber y ordenado por fecha
        return this.Where(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber)
            .OrderBy(c=> c.fecha).ToList().IndexOf(this[index]) + 1;
    }

}
```

De esta forma puedes obtener el color simplemente comprobando si la caja es la primera en la cola.